# Rails 3rd Party Services Unavaliable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter, instagram

I have the Twitter and Instagram api one of my rails app through the relevant gems and the following methods in my application controller, is there a way to wrap this code inside something that will allow the site to still run if these services are unavailable or when I am working locally without an internet connection.

#### Application Controller

```
helper_method :tweets, :instagram

def tweets
  Twitter.user_timeline("xxxxxxxx", :count => 3)
 end

def instagram
  Instagram.user_recent_media("xxxxxxxxx", :count => 6)
end
```

If I turn my wifi off then this is an error i get for the tweets method

```
Twitter::Error::ClientError at /
getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
helper_method :tweets, :instagram

def tweets
  Twitter.user_timeline("xxxxxxxx", :count => 3) rescue nil
 end

def instagram
  Instagram.user_recent_media("xxxxxxxxx", :count => 6) rescue nil
end
```

Comment: This worked perfectly after adding an if statement in the view.